# Android Source code build error

Tags: android

I am trying to build android source code in my Linux machine(Ubuntu 12.04 64bit). when I am start building it...i am getting error as follows

```
============================================ 
Checking build tools versions... 
************************************************************ 
You are attempting to build with the incorrect version of java.   
Your version is: java version "1.6.0_24". The correct version is: Java SE 1.6.   
Please follow the machine setup instructions at 
https://source.android.com/source/download.html 
************************************************************ 
build/core/main.mk:141: *** stop.  Stop.
```

I am able to understand the problem but I don't know how to change my java version because while installing jdk from terminal i am getting "1.6.0_24" version by default. 
Please do needful. 
Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 4):

Install Java SE 1.6 and use `sudo update-alternatives --config java` to set to that java version.
You can download Java from here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Charan...apart from changing the alternative, i had to install other build tools as well...

Answer (score 4):

1.) If you’ve already installed OpenJDK (Or in ubantu generally it is already installed). Remove it by running this command:
`sudo apt-get purge openjdk*`

2.) Then:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

Then update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

3.) Select which version you want
To install Oracle Java 8:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

To install Oracle Java 7:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

To install the Java 6:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java6-installer
```